# .Net BFF OAuth2 with OpenOIdConnect and Azure AD redirect loop after authentication

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I want to implement a web api which acts as a BFF for an Angular SPA and handles also the user authentication with an azure active directory. So that the backend stores the bearer token and the refresh token for the users. I have all setup in azure and configured the app.

My Redirect url looks like:

```
https://localhost/signin-oidc
```

This is my app config:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignOutScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
        options.SlidingExpiration = false;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        options.Cookie.Name = "__Host-ui";
        options.Events.OnSigningOut = async e =>
        {
            await e.HttpContext.RevokeRefreshTokenAsync();
        };
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        
        options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0";
        options.ClientId = "clientId from config";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret from config";
        
        options.UsePkce = true;
        
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
        options.ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.Query;
        
        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        options.Scope.Add("api");
        options.Scope.Add("name");
        options.Scope.Add("ipaddr");
        
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.MapInboundClaims = false;

        options.CorrelationCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.NonceCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    });

builder.Services.AddOpenIdConnectAccessTokenManagement();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

I'm using the **Duende.AccessTokenManagement** and the **Duende.AccessTokenManagement.OpenIdConnect** Nuget Packages for automatic token management.

Then I have a controller like this:

```
[ApiController]
public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("hello")]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Hello()
    {
        return new JsonResult("Hello");
    }
}
```

Which I can access and the authentication middleware redirects automaticaly to the microsoft login page. After the login a token is provided but the redirect to my redirect url seems like a endless loop between the redirect url and the hello - endpoint and after a few requests its breaking up with the error:

```
Correlation failed
```

Comment: If you're working with Azure AD, I'd recommend using the microsoft.identity.web package instead. See the BFF sample here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-6-BFF-Proxy

Comment: Thank you. This example works fine. But it's another approach which is ok. But I still don't understand the problem with my approach.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a `cookie not sticking` problem. The website backend uses tenporary cookies, eg to store the state and PKCE verifier so that they can be used before and after login. I would update these settings also, to match the main authentication cookies. Use of samesite strict is the preferred setting, with best CSRF protection.

```cs
options.NonceCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
```

Next you need to view network requests in browser tools. Use the `preserve log` option in Chrome, which will enable you to see website requests of this form. See what `cookie` request headers are being supplied, and see if they match earlier `set-cookie` response headers before the redirect. Add these details to your question if the issue persists.

```
https://localhost/signin-oidc?code=xxx&state=yyy
```

This is often the best way to troubleshoot redirect loops. Another possible cause is cookie decryption, though it looks like you are using default DPAPI settings, so I doubt that is the cause.

**SPA CONSIDERATIONS**

You are using a website security solution, which may not be the best fit for an SPA, as `derisen` indicates. The website abruptly redirects static content requests without a cookie, or when the cookie expires. You may find that the BFF sample provides an API driven solution that gives the SPA better control over redirect and other behaviour, eg when access tokens expire.